# Compare multiple columns while JOINing two tables in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I've got two tables in BigQuery that I need to join. One of them has customer information including their state, borough and city and the other one has all the same three address columns and an adittional field I need to add to the customer's table.

The problem is that the address information from the two tables come from different parts of the company and the data is not always written the same way for each zone.

Here's a quick sample of what I have in the two tables:

Table Customers:

| Name | State | Borough | City | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | New York | Manhattan | Manhattan | null |
| Marie | New York | Queens | Queens | null |

Table Zones:

| State | Borough | City | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | Manhatan | The Manhattan | EAST USA |
| New York | Queens | Quinz | EAST USA |

The expected result is an updated Customers table:

| Name | State | Borough | City | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | New York | Manhattan | Manhattan | EAST USA |
| Marie | New York | Queens | Queens | EAST USA |

I've found a very interesting solution to do a "distance" measure and comparison using the Levenshtein method [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/measuring-string-similarity-in-bigquery-using-sql-33c490638c89) but since the customer table has tens of millons of rows... it takes A LOT to process.

What could be the best approach in this scenario? Of course I know I'll get some nulls from cities/boroughs that are missing or completely wrong in either table, but I'm guessing I can get over 90% of zones if I can mix-match the 3 columns. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the latest iteration of what I've tried. Canceled after 10 minutes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT
    h.client_code,
    h.state,
    h.borough,
    h.city,
    CASE
      WHEN h.zone IS NOT NULL THEN h.zone
      WHEN z.zone IS NOT NULL THEN z.zone
      ELSE NULL
    END AS zone
  FROM `project.dataset.customers` h
  JOIN `project.dataset.zones` z
  ON (
    UPPER(h.state) = UPPER(z.state)
    AND ROUND(`project.utilities.utility_levenshtein`(h.borough, z.borough), 2) > 0.75
  )
  LIMIT 100000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fuzzy matching with BigQuery UDFs**

Use fuzzy matching UDFs like LEVENSHTEIN and SOUNDEX to join on similar borough names:

```
SELECT
  c.Name,
  c.State,
  c.Borough,
  c.City,
  z.Zone
FROM Customers c
JOIN Zones z
ON c.State = z.State
AND LEVENSHTEIN(c.Borough, z.Borough) < 3 
AND SOUNDEX(c.Borough) = SOUNDEX(z.Borough)
```

**Cluster similar strings**

Use BigQuery ML clustering functions like CLUSTER and CENTROID_DISTANCE to group similar borough names:

```
WITH Boroughs_clustered AS (
  SELECT Borough, CLUSTER(Borough) OVER() AS borough_cluster
  FROM Customers 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Borough, CLUSTER(Borough) OVER() 
  FROM Zones
)

SELECT * 
FROM Customers c
JOIN Zones z
ON c.State = z.State
AND z.borough_cluster = c.borough_cluster
Pre-process strings
```

**Approximate JOIN**

BigQuery supports approximate JOINs which can match similar strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
JOIN Zones z
APPROXIMATE ON c.Borough ~= z.Borough
WHERE c.State = z.State
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've spent all day trying some of these in many many ways but I have three problems: a) Everything is in Spanish (guess I forgot to mention that) so Soundex is not really a good option, b) APPROXIMATE doesn't seem to work with BQ (I get an error and no info on that anywhere) and c) Levenshtein works great but for just a few records. If I try to run leven on the fly with millons of records it might take hours. Tomorrow I'll keep fighting. Gonna try clustering. Thanks.

Comment: BTW what I'm trying now is applying levenshtein on a single column from each table (concatenation of the original 3 columns in each table) and still takes too long.